# Return 0 row affected MySQL

Tags: mysql, select

In MySQL, can I write a select SQL command that return 0 row affected when executing query without using table name?

I am using prepare stmt and execute stmt, and I want to receive "0 row(s) affected" in message output from MySQL when running execute.

Sample code:

```
SET @del='SELECT ...';
PREPARE stmt from @del;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Thanks for your reading.

P/s: I found a solution by using

```
SELECT 1 LIMIT 0;
```

Comment: Did you mean `SELECT 0 'rows'` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=47b96f5c3f71f39e83e147ba2d3a5150

Comment: I mean the result of query is null or empty

Comment: You usually select from a table. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Could you provide more detail for your question? Or provide some expect result?

Comment: You are using `SELECT` there isn't any affected row, why don't you use `COUNT`?

Comment: @D-Shih COUNT can be used in prepare? It is ok when using another query, but I don't want to using table name in that query.

Comment: I found a solution for this using "SELECT 1 limit 0".

Comment: *I mean the result of query is null or empty* If NULL is safe for you then use `SELECT NULL;`.

Comment: @Akina I tried to use SELECT NULL; but when executing it showed "1 rows returned" in output message.

Comment: I have citated **your** words. If the row with one row and NULL value is not safe for you then `LIMIT 0` is correct solution. Also if you need in *without using table name* because you do not know the name of any table or you do not want to access it then you may access any accessible system table or view.

Comment: `select 1 where 0` also works

Comment: @ysth it is ok without using prepare, but it will cause syntax error when using prepare stmt

Comment: *but it will cause syntax error when using prepare stmt* It fails in MySQL 5.x but works on 8+.

Comment: oh, right, before mysql 8 it would need to be `select 1 from dual where 0`